# Supply custom attribute to every ChoiceType option's label

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

In Symfony2, using a form with a `ChoiceType` field will render something like this:

```
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label>Option 1</label></span>
<span>
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label>Option 2</label></span>
<span>
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label>Option 3</label></span>
<span>
```

Using the `label_attr` function I can change the attributes of the overarching label, but I want to change the attributes of every label for every options like this:

```
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label attr="custom">Option 1</label></span>
<span>
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label attr="custom">Option 2</label></span>
<span>
<span>
  <input type="radio"><label attr="custom">Option 3</label></span>
<span>
```

Is this possible in Symfony2?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `label_attr` function should give you exactly what you're looking for.  For example, your form type:

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('someRadio', 'choice', [
                'label_attr' => ['class' => 'extra_class']
                // ... other things here
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will apply the attribute to the overarching label only, but not the labels next to the radio buttons. In my example I have a section labelled "Payment" and different options: "Visa", "MasterCard", ... `label_attr` will only affect the "Payment" label, but I want to change the attributes of the "Visa", "mastercard" labels.

Comment: Have you tried it?  I just tried this out and the labels were applied in the exact way that you wanted, on each radio button, not the overarching label.